# Golang IO reading file invalid memory address

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I'm having some troubles trying to read a GZIP file from AWS S3.
I have only a simple code and I'm getting the error `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`. But it still hard to find the problem.

The error message is saying that is the `gzip.NewReader...`. Why `golang` is reporting it? How could i solve it?

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hensg/pushego/aws.GetGZIPProductsDump(0x7ffead44098f, 0xc, 0x7ffead44099f, 0x2f, 0x0, 0xc420190580, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/henrique/go/src/github.com/hensg/pushego/aws/s3.go:47 +0x2e7
main.main()
        /home/henrique/go/src/github.com/hensg/pushego/pushego.go:28 +0x249
```

Main code (pushego.go)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/hensg/pushego/aws"
)

func init() {
    log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Starting...")

    var bucket, key string
    var timeout time.Duration

    flag.StringVar(&bucket, "b", "", "Bucket name")
    flag.StringVar(&key, "k", "", "Object key name")
    flag.DurationVar(&timeout, "d", 0, "Download timeout")
    flag.Parse()

    gzipReader, err := aws.GetGZIPDump(bucket, key, timeout) // line 28
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to create GZIP reader")
    }
   defer gzipReader.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(gzipReader)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        log.Printf("Read: %s\n", scanner.Text())
    }

    log.Printf("Successfully download file from %s/%s\n", bucket, key)
}
```

Aws code (aws/s3.go)

```
package aws

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

func GetGZIPProductsDump(bucket, key string, timeout time.Duration) (*gzip.Reader, error) {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    // Create a context with a timeout that will abort the download if it takes
    // more than the passed in timeout.
    ctx := context.Background()
    var cancelFn func()
    if timeout > 0 {
        ctx, cancelFn = context.WithTimeout(ctx, timeout)
    }
    // Ensure the context is canceled to prevent leaking.
    // See context package for more information, https://golang.org/pkg/context/
    defer cancelFn()

    // Uploads the object to S3. The Context will interrupt the request if the
    // timeout expires.
    resp, err := svc.GetObjectWithContext(ctx, &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    })
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok && aerr.Code() == request.CanceledErrorCode {
            // If the SDK can determine the request or retry delay was canceled
            // by a context the CanceledErrorCode error code will be returned.
            log.Fatal("Download canceled due to timeout, %v\n", err)
        } else {
            log.Fatal("Failed to download object, %v\n", err)
        }
    }

    return gzip.NewReader(resp.Body) // line 47
}
```

Comment: @Flimzy I added full code including comments now. No, i don't have any other deffered statements. I tried to add `defer gzipReader.Close()` after error checking but still doesn't working.

Comment: @Flimzy my bad. It was saying that the problematic line was `gzip.NewReader(...)`. I tried to defer but still not working

Comment: So what is the meaning of `// line 28` at the end of your first code snippet?

Comment: if `gzip.NewReader()` is giving an `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` error, it probably means that `resp` or `resp.Body` are nil.

Comment: Fixed `// line 28` on wrong line

Comment: Put the line `defer cancelFn()` inside the if, currently cancelFn() is not set if the timeout is 0, that provokes​ a null pointer when the defer is executed.

Comment: oohh thank you @Motakjuq!! It works! Post an answer and I will accept. This example is a copy/past from AWS SKD for GO. So, probably another people will have the same issue.
Copy from: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related with the `defer cancelFn()`, currently that func is not set if the timeout is 0, this provoke a panic with a null pointer, so, you should move the `defer` inside of the previous if statement because it's the only point when is required to be used. The code of `aws/s3.go` have to be as the following.

```golang
...
// Create a context with a timeout that will abort the download if it takes
// more than the passed in timeout.
ctx := context.Background()
var cancelFn func()
if timeout > 0 {
    ctx, cancelFn = context.WithTimeout(ctx, timeout)
    // Ensure the context is canceled to prevent leaking.
    // See context package for more information, https://golang.org/pkg/context/
    defer cancelFn()
}
...
```